# Grouped bar chart with WinForms Chart Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, microsoft-chart-controls

I can create with MS Excel Grouped bar chart like this.
[image]

I need to create the same Chart via  WinForms Chart Control.

I try this code but it seems like I need more sophisticated solution to build correct chart like it does MS Excel.

So help me to correct code in order to build grouped bar chart, please.
(And this great Microsoft example does not help https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418 )

**DataSource**

```
DataTable dtExc = new DataTable();

// Create columns
dtExc.Columns.Add((new DataColumn("StoodType", typeof(int))).Caption = "Stood");
dtExc.Columns.Add((new DataColumn("TotalMinutes", typeof(double))).Caption = "Time");

foreach (var exDataitem in allDataExc)
{
     DataRow drToAdd = dtExc.NewRow();

     drToAdd[0] = exDataitem.StoodTypeFullName;
     drToAdd[1] = exDataitem.TotalMinutes;

     dtExc.Rows.Add(drToAdd);   
}
```

**Chart**

```
public Chart GenerateExcChart(DataTable dtChartDataSource, int width, int height, string bgColor, SeriesChartType seriesChartType,
            string axisXTitle, string axisYTitle)
        {
            Chart chart = new Chart()
            {
                Width = width,
                Height = height
            };


            chart.Legends.Add(new Legend() { Name = "Legend" });
            chart.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
            ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea() { Name = "ChartArea" };

            //Remove X-axis grid lines
            chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
            chartArea.AxisX.Title = axisXTitle;

            chartArea.AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
            chartArea.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;

            //Remove Y-axis grid lines
            chartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
            chartArea.AxisY.Interval = 1;
            chartArea.AxisY.Title = axisYTitle;

            //Chart Area Back Color
            chartArea.BackColor = Color.FromName(bgColor);
            chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
            chart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
            string series = string.Empty;

            //create series and add data points to the series
            if (dtChartDataSource != null)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dtChartDataSource.Columns)
                {
                    //a series to the chart
                    if (chart.Series.FindByName(dc.ColumnName) == null)
                    {
                        series = dc.ColumnName;
                        chart.Series.Add(series);
                        chart.Series[series].ChartType = seriesChartType;
                    }

                    var rowIndex = 0;
                    //Add data points to the series
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dtChartDataSource.Rows)
                    {
                        double dataPoint = 0;
                        double.TryParse(dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString(), out dataPoint);

                        var objDataPoint = new DataPoint();
                        objDataPoint.YValues = new double[] { dataPoint };
                        objDataPoint.XValue = rowIndex + 1;
                        objDataPoint.AxisLabel = rowIndex.ToString();

                        if (dataPoint == 0)
                        {
                            objDataPoint.IsEmpty = true;
                        }

                        chart.Series[series].Points.Add(objDataPoint);
                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }

            return chart;
        }
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Why do you need a more sophisticated solution?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé The code I have for bar chart does not create chart I need.

Comment: In what way? Currently this is a "why is this code not working?" question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using Google and some experiments I corrected code so it does what I need.

```
public Chart GenerateExcChart(DataTable dtChartDataSource, int width, int height, string bgColor, SeriesChartType seriesChartType,
            string axisXTitle, string axisYTitle)
        {
            Chart chart = new Chart()
            {
                Width = width,
                Height = height
            };

            chart.Legends.Add(new Legend() { Name = "Legend" });
            chart.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
            ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea() { Name = "ChartArea" };

            chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;//Remove X-axis grid lines
            chartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;//Remove Y-axis grid lines

            chartArea.AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
            chartArea.AxisY.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
            chartArea.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
            chartArea.AxisY.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;

            chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -45;

            chartArea.AxisX.Title = axisYTitle;
            chartArea.AxisY.Title = axisXTitle;

            //Chart Area Back Color
            chartArea.BackColor = Color.FromName(bgColor);
            chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
            chart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
            string series = string.Empty;

            //create series and add data points to the series
            if (dtChartDataSource != null)
            {
                series = "Series1";
                chart.Series.Add(series);
                chart.Series[series].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
                chart.Series[series].XValueType = ChartValueType.Auto;
                chart.Series[series].YValuesPerPoint = 1;
                chart.Series[series].YValueType = ChartValueType.Auto;

                var rowIndex = 0;

                //Add data points to the series
                foreach (DataRow dr in dtChartDataSource.Rows)
                {
                    double dataPoint;
                    DataPoint objDataPoint = new DataPoint();

                    objDataPoint.AxisLabel = dr[dtChartDataSource.Columns[0].ColumnName].ToString();

                    double.TryParse(dr[dtChartDataSource.Columns[1].ColumnName].ToString(), out dataPoint);


                    objDataPoint.XValue = rowIndex;
                    objDataPoint.YValues = new double[] { dataPoint };

                    chart.Series[series].Points.Add(objDataPoint);

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }

            chart.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = false;

            return chart;
        }
```